# Replace multiple instances of a letter in a word with a single letter in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

```
line = "Pleeeeease"
```

To make it into Please by condensing multiple e's together. I know the code in Ruby

```
line.gsub!(/(.)\1{2,}/, '\1')
```

How do I do the same in Python?

Answer (score 6):

Use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html) function.

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "Pleeeeease"
>>> re.sub(r'(.)\1{2,}', r'\1', line)
'Please'
```

This would replace three or more consecutive same character with that particular single character.

```
>>> re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', line)
'Please'
```

This would replace two or more consecutive same character with that particular single character.

Answer (score 1):

A non regex way:

```
print("".join([ch if ch != line[ind+1:ind+2] else "" for ind, ch in enumerate(line)]))


In [44]: line = "Pleeeeeeeeeeasee"    
In [45]:  "".join([ch if ch != line[ind+1:ind+2] else "" for ind, ch in enumerate(line)])
Out[45]: 'Please'
In [46]: line = "Pleease"
In [47]:  "".join([ch if ch != line[ind+1:ind+2] else "" for ind, ch in enumerate(line)])
Out[47]: 'Please'
```